# What modifications to the server results in the use of a .p8 instead of an old .pem?

Tags: php, server, ssl-certificate, apple-push-notifications

I would first say .p8 vs .pem, but the real question for me is: **what should i change in my php** on the server if I replace my .pem with a .p8 to send remote push notifications ?

Thanks for reading.
Cheers

Comment: The only difference is the file extension. Change nothing.

Comment: Thank you Sammitch, shouldn't php read the bundle ID in case of p8 and if so how?